# Required tag is not working in Bootstrap form

Tags: html, flask, bootstrap-5

This is a Bootstrap form which I need to add to my flask website. I need all the values to be filled before submission of the form. I only know of "required" to make the values mandatory before submitting. But its not working.
Am new to web dev, I have tried all the permutations and combinations of what I can think of, but am not able to make this form support mandatory fields. Any help will be appreciated.
The required tag is in all the input tags, but still form is being submitted without any prompt.

```
 <form
    name="sentMessage"
    action="/#top5cars"
    method="post"
    novalidate
    autocomplete="off"
  >
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <img
          src="{{ url_for('static', filename='assets/img/car.jpg')}}"
          class="img-fluid"
          alt=""
        />
      </div>




      <div class="col-lg-6 mt-5 mt-lg-0 d-flex">
        <div class="row align-self-center gy-4">
          <div class="col-md-7" data-aos="zoom-out" data-aos-delay="200">
            <div class="feature-box d-flex align-items-center">
             
              <input type="number" class="form-control no-border"
              id="cost_min" placeholder="Cost Min"
              value={{inp_data["cost_min"]}}
              name="cost_min" required>
              
              <input type="number"
              class="form-control no-border" id="cost_max"
              placeholder={{inp_data["cost_max"]}} name="cost_max" required
              >
            </div>
          </div>



          

          <div class="col-md-5" data-aos="zoom-out" data-aos-delay="300">
            <div class="feature-box d-flex align-items-center">
              <input required type="text" class="form-control no-border"
              id="brand" placeholder={{inp_data["brand"]}} name="brand" >
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-7" data-aos="zoom-out" data-aos-delay="300">
            <div class="feature-box d-flex align-items-center">
              <input type="number" class="form-control no-border"
              id="mileage_min" placeholder={{inp_data["mileage_min"]}}
              name="mileage_min" required > 
              
              <input type="number"
              class="form-control no-border" id="mileage_max"
              placeholder={{inp_data["mileage_max"]}} name="mileage_max"
              required >
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-5" data-aos="zoom-out" data-aos-delay="300">
            <div class="feature-box d-flex align-items-center">
              <select
                class="form-select no-border"
                aria-label="Default select example"
                name="type"
                id="type"
              >
                <option selected>{{inp_data["type"]}}</option>
                <option value="Petrol">Petrol</option>
                <option value="Diesel">Diesel</option>
                <option value="CNG">CNG</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-7" data-aos="zoom-out" data-aos-delay="300">
            <div class="feature-box d-flex align-items-center">
              <select
                class="form-select no-border"
                aria-label="Default select example"
                name="Seating_Cap"
                id="Seating_Cap"
              >
                <option selected>{{inp_data["Seating_Cap"]}}</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="16">16</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-5" data-aos="zoom-out" data-aos-delay="700">
            <div class="feature-box d-flex align-items-center">
              <button name = "santabanta" type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" onclick="scrollxyz">
                Submit
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

I am using this Bootstrap form in a Flask project.

Answer (score 0):

The browser-default form-validation gets deactivated with the attribute [`novalidate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-novalidate). If you remove that, it should work. But in case you want to use custom styles or the [pre-defined styles from bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/validation/), the `novalidate`-attribute is correct.
If that is the case, then you should implement your own form-validation on the client-side with javascript or with your backend.

In most cases I'd recommend you to do a client-side form-validation. However, always be aware that the dom can be easily manipulated by the user (e.g. browser dev-tools). Thus, depending on the project it makes sense to validate the final submitted data in your back-end, too.